# Django tastypie reverse relation not working

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have following CustomerProfile models that OneToOne maps to the User table :

```
class CustomerProfile(models.Model):
'''Profile details of the customers. All extra details are mentioned        
here.'''
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'testapp'

    def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.user)
```

I have created REST API using Tastpye framework with following resource.py to fetch user and its profile details

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):                                                                  
'''Fetch user details'''                                                                        

    class Meta:                                                                                     
        queryset = User.objects.all()                                                               
        resource_name = 'user'                                                                      
        include_resource_uri = False                                                                
        allowed_methods = ['get']                                                                   
        excludes = ['password','last_login','is_superuser','is_staff','date_joined']                
        filtering = {                                                                               
            'id': ['exact'],                                                                        
            'username': ['exact']                                                                   
        }                                                                                           

class CustomerProfileResource(ModelResource):                                                       
'''Fetch customer details and all coupons'''                                                    

    class Meta:                                                                                     
        queryset = CustomerProfile.objects.all()                                                    
        resource_name = 'customer'                                                                  
        include_resource_uri = False                                                                
        allowed_methods = ['get']
```

Now what I want is the with a single API call (/user) user will able to fetch its profile details also. Can anybody tell how to do that.
Just for reference I have added following code in UserResource class to achieve this :

```
profile = fields.ToManyField('coin.api.CustomerProfileResource', 'profile', null=True, full=True)
```

But I am getting this error :

```
{"error_message": "'CustomerProfile' object has no attribute 'all'", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File \"/home/rajeev/projects/bitbucket/coin/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 195, in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I have surfed a lot to achieve this, but haven't  found anything which can achieve the desired output. Please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CustomerProfile bind to User with one-to-one relationship, so you should to use fields.OneToOneField in UserResource:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):                                                                  
    '''Fetch user details'''                                                                        
    custom_profile = fields.OneToOneField(CustomerProfileResource, 'custom_profile', related_name='profile', full=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'custom_profile']  # other fields what you need
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Luckly I got the answer by hit and trial :)

As CustomerProfile resource is mapped to the UserResouce by OneToOne mapping so we have to  use fields.ToOneField instead of  fields.ToManyField while doing the reverse relation from UserResource as following :

```
profile = fields.ToOneField('coin.api.CustomerProfileResource', 'profile', null=True, full=True)
```

But still if somebody could able to clarify the  resource mapping and reverse mapping clearly, that will be quite helpful for all, apparently django official documentation was not able to help me a lot.

Thanks